# Not able to deserialize JSON array into C# list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I have a json array as below

```
{
"odata.metadata": "https://testapp.mycomp.com/$metadata#UnitDetail",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "UnitId": 238905,
        "Active": false,
        "Name": "Rakesh",
        "ContactNumber": "0070002934"           
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "UnitId": 238906,
        "Active": true,
        "Name": "Rahul",
        "ContactNumber": "123444003"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "UnitId": 238907,
        "Active": true,
        "Name": "Rohit",
        "ContactNumber": "1227032932"
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to deserialize it into c# list as below

```
 var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnitDetail[]>(json);
```

My c# class is a below

```
  public class UnitDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

}
```

But this code is not deserializing it.

I have also tried codes as below but none seems working

```
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  UnitDetail[] serializedData= js.Deserialize<UnitDetail[]>(json);
```

and also like below

```
List<UnitDetail> serializedData= js.Deserialize<List<UnitDetail>>(json);
```

I am really not sure why it is not working. Any help would really be appriciable.

Thanks

Comment: What error you are getting in `List<UnitDetail> serializedData= js.Deserialize<List<UnitDetail>>(json);` This seems to be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a root object

```
public class UnitDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string odata_metadata { get; set; }
    public List<UnitDetail> value { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize as

```
 var root = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `JsonHelper.Deserialize`

```
List<UnitDetail> data = JsonHelper.Deserialize<List<UnitDetail>>(json);
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".