# Deserialize JSON array into c# list

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON array into a list of objects. I know how to normally do this but the JSON is returning in a format I don't know how to with.

```
{
    "result": {
        "account": [
            {
                "id": "18192504834",
                "ownerID": null,
                "accountName": "Citrix",
                "industry": null,
                "phone": "",
                "annualRevenue": null,
                "numberOfEmployees": "0",
                "website": "",
                "yearStarted": null,
                "fax": null,
                "billingCity": null,
                "billingCountry": null,
                "billingPostalCode": null,
                "billingState": null,
                "billingStreetAddress": null,
                "shippingCity": null,
                "shippingCountry": null,
                "shippingPostalCode": null,
                "shippingState": null,
                "shippingStreetAddress": null,
                "account_status_634798fb3a786": null,
                "company_linkedin_url_6347990655c57": null,
                "focus_area___primary_634799ab2f32f": null,
                "normalised___industry_634799cabc901": null,
                "normalised___number_of_employees_63479a161a8e2": null,
                "target_markets_63479a4007cd9": null,
                "focus_area___secondary_63479a64b0d21": null,
                "normalised___address_1_63479aa361d84": null,
                "normalised___address_2_63479ac2a3ede": null,
                "normalised___town__city_63479acf156f5": null,
                "normalised___state_63479b13aa948": null,
                "normalised___post_code_63479b66a1b77": null,
                "normalised___country_63479c84d2e4d": null,
                "normalised___region_63479cb3129f9": null,
                "bulk_import_list_source_63479cd899e77": null,
                "cwid_635887724a213": null
            },
```

Here is the class I am trying to convert it into

```
    public class Account{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string ownerID { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string AnnualRevenue { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfEmployees { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string YearStarted { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string BillingCity { get; set; }
        public string BillingCountry { get; set; }
        public string BillingPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string BillingState { get; set; }
        public string BillingStreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCountry { get; set; }
        public string ShippingPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ShippingState { get; set; }
        public string ShippingStreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public string CompanyLinkedinURL { get; set; }
        public string FocusArea { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedIndustry { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedNumberOfEmployees { get; set; }
        public string TargetMarkets { get; set; }
        public string FocusAreaSecondary { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedAddress { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedAddressTwo { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedTownCity { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedState { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedPostCode { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedCountry { get; set; }
        public string NormalisedRegion { get; set; }
        public string BulkImportList { get; set; }
        public string CWID { get; set; } 
    }
```

Here is how I am retrieving the JSON and attempting to deserialize it

```
var request2 = new RestRequest()
{
    Method = Method.Post,
    Timeout = 300000
};

var SharpSpringClient = new RestClient("https://api.sharpspring.com/pubapi/v1.2/?accountID=&secretKey=");
var json = "{\"method\":\"getAccounts\",\"id\":\"zapier_getaccount\",\"params\":{\"where\":{}}}";
request2.AddStringBody(json, ContentType.Json);
RestResponse response2 = SharpSpringClient.Execute(request2);
var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(response2.Content);
```

This then fails with Cannot deserialize the current JSON object..... I know it's failing because a list of Accounts doesn't account for the result and account json objects.

I also tried the answer from this question [Not able to deserialize JSON array into C# list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501351/not-able-to-deserialize-json-array-into-c-sharp-list) and made these classes

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public string result { get; set; }
        public RootAccount rootAccount { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootAccount
    {
        [JsonProperty("account")]
        public string account { get; set; }
        public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

But it then fails with this [image]

Comment: it looks like you are trying to jam an array into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your class structure should look something like this

```
public class Result
{
    public List<Account> account { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

For deserializing:

```
var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response2.Content);
```

Comment: This fixes the error but the result object is null

Comment: In addition to this, you need to change your deserialization to ```        var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response2.Content);
```

Comment: Yeah I did and am getting a null for the result object